# How can I fix choppy audio?

Tags: sound, 15.10, pulseaudio, lxde

I have a little Sony VAIO P series computer on which is installed Ubuntu 15.10 running LXDE. I've found that all audio played on the device is choppy, everything from MP4 videos played on VLC, to Skype, to Festival, is choppy. Here is a sound recording to illustrate:

https://clyp.it/vp1j2q2j

From `aplay -l`, I can see that the hardware playback device is HDA Intel MID ALC275. What could be going wrong and how could I try to fix it?

Comment: Are you using pulseaudio or Alsa?

Comment: @zwork Hi there. I'm using PulseAudio.

Comment: Try this - http://askubuntu.com/questions/138266/distorted-and-choppy-audio

Comment: You could also try this - http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2181335&page=2

Comment: @bodhi.zazen Thanks for the suggestion. I added `options snd-hda-intel model=generic` to `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf` and rebooted, but it doesn't seem to work in my case unfortunately.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Edit the file `/etc/pulse/default.pa`.

Find the following line:

```
load-module module-udev-detect
```

Change the line to the following:

```
load-module module-udev-detect tsched=0
```

Restart PulseAudio:

```
pulseaudio -k
```

Should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks for this solution :) Wonder what this option actually does - and why it is not set by default?

Comment: Thanks! It helped me, with a more horrible audio distortion issue. See also https://askubuntu.com/questions/371595/for-pulseaudio-what-does-tsched-do-and-what-are-the-defaults

Comment: can you provide an explanation of the commands and why they are needed?

Comment: This solution also worked for me on Ubuntu 20.04, with an NVidia 1070/GP104 providing HDMI audio (no audio devices on the other end of the HDMI cables, but it's apparently enabled) and an Intel 100 Series/C230 Series audio device. Thank you so much for the solution, I have been looking for this for a really long time. :-)

Comment: @PedroRodrigues The answer you are looking for is described here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/371595/for-pulseaudio-what-does-tsched-do-and-what-are-the-defaults

Comment: The intent of my question was to keep the answer self sufficient. But since your link is to this website I guess its ok. The OP could remove the question I guess.

Comment: `pulseaudio -k` results in `E: [pulseaudio] main.c: Failed to kill daemon: No such process`

Answer (score 5):

The solution for me was to edit `/etc/pulse/daemon.conf`

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/pulse/daemon.conf
```

Find the line

```
; resample-method =
```

uncomment (remove the `;`) and change to

```
resample-method = src-sinc-best-quality
```

If the line is not there at all, then add it.

Reboot for changes to take effect.

Comment: It worked on Kubuntu 20.04 for me, Kernel version 5.4.0-66 generic, 64 bit OS. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

For me none of the above worked. My issue appears to have been with `adb` (Android Debugging Bridge). I resolved my issue simply by stopping the adb server with the following command: `adb kill-server`.

Wanted to share in case anyone else was having the same issue while using `adb`

This likely does not apply to a lot of people.

Comment: Tried all the scheduling, sample rate settings, removing modules, distro hopping, ... But it was ADB running as a SystemD service all along! Thank you so much!

Comment: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/150888445 corresponding google issue

Answer (score 2):

I just ran into a similar issue with Skype 8 (skypeforlinux).

Here are the instructions that solved my pulseaudio configuration problem.

> 2. Resolve Choppy sound in (Pulseaudio) -> Skype
>
> In /etc/pulse/daemon.conf two lines has to be also substituted:

```
; default-sample-rate = 44100
```

> Should become;

```
; default-sample-rate = 48000
```

HT: [PCFreak.Net](http://www.pc-freak.net/blog/how-to-fix-pulseaudio-and-skype-crappy-sound-glitches-choppy-sound-and-crackling-on-debian-gnu-linux/)

Your mileage may vary. Best of luck!

Comment: My output was really choppy on CM106 like device (using SPDIF out) and it stopped being that way only after using 96000 default sample rate. I am also using the above suggestions but they did not make a difference themselves.

Comment: This seems to have solved it for my RME Babyface and pulseaudio 14.2

Answer (score 2):

None of the above fixes worked for me (pulseaudio 11.1); what solved it for me was going into `/etc/pulse/daemon.conf` and turning off realtime-scheduling by adding in the line `realtime-scheduling = no` beneath the line reading `;realtime-scheduling = yes` like so:

```
;realtime-scheduling = yes
realtime-scheduling = no
```

This completely fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

I also had same issue. I first watch this => https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v3Eyu4a1XD4  it didn't solve problem. but i kept all changes which are done according to video. then I enter following command,

$ sudo nano /etc/pulse/daemon.conf

it will open daemon.conf, then locate " *;realtime-scheduling = yes* " using arrow down/up and remove " ; " and change it to " r*ealtime-scheduling = no* ". then save it (press Ctrl+o then enter)(quit => Ctrl+x).
finally, run following command **or** restart computer.

$ systemctl --user restart pulseaudio.service

it was done job for me. Good luck. :)

Comment: What is the point of watching the video?

Comment: This error occur for beginners who install linux/ubuntu most of the time. So they don't know about command line text editors like vi,nano. In video, youtuber explain how to go into file and how to manupulate cord. Thts why i add that link to that answer. just for help beginners.