# Sound stopped working after some minutes?

Tags: 14.04, sound, alsa

I guess it happened at the last update. My sound suddenly stopped working. I tried to reinstall the sound devices:

```
apt-get remove --purge alsa-base pulseaudio

apt-get install alsa-base pulseaudio

sudo alsa force-reload
```

It didn't work, still no sound. I got the following output:

```
Terminating processes: 10398 13040
13040
13040 13210
13210
13210 13381
13381
13381 (with SIGKILL:) 13552
13552
13552 (failed: processes still using sound devices: 13725(pulseaudio)).
/sbin/alsa: Warning: Processes using sound devices: 13725(pulseaudio). 
Unloading ALSA sound driver modules: snd-seq-midi snd-seq-midi-event snd-seq snd-hda-codec-via snd-hda-intel snd-hda-codec snd-usb-audio snd-usbmidi-lib snd-hwdep snd-pcm snd-page-alloc snd-rawmidi snd-seq-device snd-timer (failed: modules still loaded: snd-hda-codec-via snd-hda-intel snd-hda-codec snd-usb-audio snd-usbmidi-lib snd-hwdep snd-pcm snd-page-alloc snd-rawmidi snd-seq-device snd-timer).
Loading ALSA sound driver modules: snd-seq-midi snd-seq-midi-event snd-seq snd-hda-codec-via snd-hda-intel snd-hda-codec snd-usb-audio snd-usbmidi-lib snd-hwdep snd-pcm snd-page-alloc snd-rawmidi snd-seq-device snd-timer.
```

When I execute `aplay -l` I get the following output:

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: SB [HDA ATI SB], device 0: VT1708S Analog [VT1708S Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: SB [HDA ATI SB], device 3: VT1708S Digital [VT1708S Digital]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

It seems that one device is suddenly started twice and using the same resources. That's why one blocks the other one, I guess. What can I do?

**[UPDATE]**
First of all I was able to get it running again by the following commands:

```
killall pulseaudio; rm -r ~/.config/pulse/* ; rm -r ~/.pulse*
```

wait ten seconds, then run this:

```
pulseaudio -k 

apt-get remove --purge alsa-base pulseaudio

apt-get install alsa-base pulseaudio
```

But after playing some minutes it stopped working again. 
It worked when the output of `aplay -l` looks like this (see the subdevices):

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: SB [HDA ATI SB], device 0: VT1708S Analog [VT1708S Analog]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: SB [HDA ATI SB], device 3: VT1708S Digital [VT1708S Digital]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

It obviously does not work when the subdevices are both `1/1`. But why is this switching and how can I stop it?

**[UPDATE]**
I rebooted. It worked again after reboot but after some minutes playing it suddenly stopped working again. I can confirm, that it worked while one subdevice was 0/1, the other 1/1, and as it stopped working, both are 1/1?

**[UPDATE]**
I added the following line

```
options snd-hda-intel model=generic
```

to

`/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf`

...restarted and didn't have a crash for a while now. I hope this was the solution.

**[UPDATE]**
Didn't work. Subdevices changed again. No sound.

Comment: Those are two output ports that are part of the same device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround for now. It's described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/707171/how-to-fix-choppy-audio).

```
Edit the file /etc/pulse/default.pa.

Find the following line:

load-module module-udev-detect

Change the line to the following:

module-udev-detect tsched=0
```

However, it somehow disabled pulseaudio but I don't see any disadvantage for now.