# Audio cutting out intermittently

Tags: 20.04, sound, pulseaudio

I have an issue on Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS where the the audio on my HP Omen laptop cuts out for ~1 second at a time, usually shortly after going from "no audio playing" -> "some audio playing", see [this video I recorded](https://imgur.com/a/2K3ksex). Prolonged continuous audio (e.g. youtube video) is fine.

This issue occurs across applications (vlc, chrome, firefox, system sounds test) and audio sources (music, video calls, videos) but appears to only happen for the laptops main speakers. Audio through bluetooth headphones and the dedicated audio jack appears to be fine (I'm 100% sure this was a problem through BT headphones as well, but can't reproduce it right now...).

I have tried all the solutions from [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1044552/audio-stuttering-in-ubuntu-18-04), as well as the posts it links to in the description, but none of them have helped.

Some logs from running a video through VLC (captured between un-pausing and re-pausing a video):

```
main debug: auto hiding mouse cursor
main debug: VoutDisplayEvent 'mouse button' 0 t=6
main debug: VoutDisplayEvent 'mouse button' 0 t=7
main debug: toggling pause
main debug: toggling pause
main warning: playback too late (108710): up-sampling
pulse debug: suspended
pulse debug: changing sink 4: alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3-platform-skl_hda_dsp_generic.HiFi__hw_sofhdadsp__sink (sof-hda-dsp Speaker + Headphones)
pulse debug: started
main warning: playback way too late (249408): flushing buffers
vlcpulse debug: write index corrupt
pulse debug: cannot synchronize start
pulse debug: deferring start (1108711 us)
vlcpulse debug: write index corrupt
pulse debug: cannot synchronize start
pulse debug: deferring start (1107639 us)
vlcpulse debug: write index corrupt
pulse debug: cannot synchronize start
pulse debug: deferring start (1107516 us)
pulse debug: deferring start (1019343 us)
pulse debug: deferring start (1019317 us)
pulse debug: deferring start (1019288 us)
pulse debug: deferring start (1019265 us)
pulse debug: deferring start (1018679 us)
pulse debug: changing sink 4: alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3-platform-skl_hda_dsp_generic.HiFi__hw_sofhdadsp__sink (sof-hda-dsp Speaker + Headphones)
pulse debug: deferring start (1018399 us)
pulse debug: deferring start (996159 us)
pulse debug: deferring start (973979 us)
pulse debug: deferring start (951809 us)
pulse debug: deferring start (929681 us)
pulse debug: deferring start (907596 us)
pulse debug: deferring start (885530 us)
pulse debug: deferring start (863449 us)
pulse debug: deferring start (841398 us)
pulse debug: deferring start (819327 us)
pulse debug: deferring start (795487 us)
main debug: toggling resume
main debug: toggling resume
dbus_screensaver debug: got cookie 2018993637
main debug: auto hiding mouse cursor
main debug: auto hiding mouse cursor
pulse debug: suspended
pulse debug: changing sink 4: alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3-platform-skl_hda_dsp_generic.HiFi__hw_sofhdadsp__sink (sof-hda-dsp Speaker + Headphones)
main debug: auto hiding mouse cursor
```

There is no output from `dmesg` during the playback from vlc (other than `audit` messages).

Comment: Hello and welcome to askubuntu - If you want an answer to your questions, you should enable as to reproduce or retrace the issue. The video does not help. Proposal: First make sure, that the problem is not coming from the video source (if youtube is working, its sound like a source issue). Check the errors and warnings from the video player - e.g. `vlc` is very chatty when it comes to frame drops or buffer overruns. Last, check `dmesg` for any audio related errors or warnings - Post all fo that and someone might be able to help you

Comment: Updated the description with more details. Sorry, I had meant to ask directly for which info would be most helpful to add to the post, wasn't sure where to even begin debugging this...

Comment: I don't have a solution, but I am pretty sure, the "changing sink x" is the result of the real issue. Because the sink should not change until you change something (e.g. unplug head phones)