# Crackling/static in Discord with default audio output port (PulseAudio)

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, headphones

I installed Ubuntu 18.04 less than a week ago and 99% of what I need to work has been no problem. When I first installed Discord, from the instructions on their website, everything was fine. The Snap package had problems starting and refused to go past the update sequence, as if it had no internet connection. However, the first time I join a voice chat after a reboot, I get loud crackling anytime someone speaks. It fixes itself if I change the output of my headphones from Line Out to Headphones or vice versa (headphones setting sounds better to me).

I initially thought it was the Line Out setting being the issue, so I changed it using [this as a guide](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/175930/change-default-port-for-pulseaudio-line-out-not-headphones). That did not fix it and no matter which one I set as default, the crackling returns equally as bad in Discord until I change it. After that, either port sounds just fine. I'm trying to figure out how I can have it sound good without having to flip the setting in PulseAudio, but I'm clueless.

All other audio seems fine. Even in games like CSGO there isn't this problem with voice chat, and I'm able to play other games, watch video, and listen to spotify just fine. It only seems to be affecting discord.

If it matters, the exact settings are "Line Out (plugged in)" and "Headphones (unplugged)" although despite the forum in the link above, I was able to set the Headphones as default anyway and it recognizes that port. I'm using the PulseAudio Volume Control (pavucontrol) app from Ubuntu Software to change these settings, and the terminal to set the default port.

My only connected audio devices are my headphones for output, plugged into the motherboard port; my mixer and headphones are listed in input (headphone mic muted), both also plugged into the motherboard. Mixer is a USB interface. My webcam was listed at one point, but I'm not sure where it has gone and if that can affect things somehow.

If anyone knows of a fix, please let me know! Thank you

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I fixed it by modify `/etc/pulse/default.pa`. Find and replace:

`load-module module-udev-detect`

by

`load-module module-udev-detect tsched=0`

Then restart PulseAudio using this command:

`pulseaudio -k && sudo alsa force-reload`

Comment: That was it exactly. What does that do/why does that work?

Comment: I think it's the conflict between Discord and PulseAudio. Refs https://askubuntu.com/questions/371595/for-pulseaudio-what-does-tsched-do-and-what-are-the-defaults

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue with Skyrim on Linux via. Steam Play. I tried all kinds of stuff; these were the only things that actually worked, so they must be important.

---

To get music and voices working, this is what worked for me:

> 1. enable Steam Beta client, restart
> 2. Settings > Steam Play > Enable Steam Play for all titles
> 3. install Skyrim through Steam
> 4. install `winetricks` (i.e. `apt install winetricks`)
> 5. find the directory `steamapps/compatdata/489830` and ensure it has a `pfx` directory. `cd` into it.
> 6. execute `WINEPREFIX=$PWD/pfx winetricks --force xact`
> 7. execute `WINEPREFIX=$PWD/pfx winecfg`
> 8. in the Libraries tab create overrides for the properties `xaudio2_6` and `xaudio2_7`, setting both to `native`
>
> You'll know it works, if you hear the introductory music on the title
>   screen.

Source: https://www.reddit.com/r/linux_gaming/comments/99i4se/skyrim_on_linux_steam_play_no_voiceno_music_audio/

### ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

I also had some kind of popping, crackling, or distortion of the audio after I got music and voices working. This is what worked for me:

> Laggy sound
>
> This issue is due to incorrect buffer sizes. First verify that the
>   variables `default-fragments` and `default-fragment-size-msec` are not
>   being set to non default values in the file `/etc/pulse/daemon.conf`. If
>   the issue is still present, try setting them to the following values:
>
> `/etc/pulse/daemon.conf`
>
> `default-fragments = 5`
>
> `default-fragment-size-msec = 2`
>
> ### ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
>
> Choppy/distorted sound
>
> This can result from an incorrectly set sample rate. Try the following
>   setting:
>
> `/etc/pulse/daemon.conf`
>
> `avoid-resampling = yes #(Needs PA11 or higher)`
>
> `default-sample-rate = 48000`
>
> and restart the PulseAudio server.
>
> ---
>
> If one experiences choppy sound in applications using OpenAL, change
>   the sample rate in `/etc/openal/alsoft.conf`:
>
> `/etc/openal/alsoft.conf`
>
> `frequency = 48000`
>
> ---
>
> Setting the PCM volume above 0 dB can cause clipping. Running
>   `alsamixer` will allow you to see if this is the problem and if so fix
>   it. Note that ALSA may not correctly export the dB information to
>   PulseAudio. Try the following:
>
> `/etc/pulse/default.pa`
>
> `load-module module-udev-detect ignore_dB=1`
>
> and restart the PulseAudio server.

Source: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PulseAudio/Troubleshooting#Laggy_sound

Answer (score 0):

Here's an easy way to do what [Jared Chu suggested](https://askubuntu.com/a/1107795/527764):

```
sed -i 's/^load-module module-udev-detect$/load-module module-udev-detect tsched=0/g' /etc/pulse/default.pa && 
pulseaudio -k && 
sudo alsa force-reload
```

(Please let me know if I can improve this approach)