# audio problems Ubuntu 20.04 intel nuc 8i7hvk

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, hdmi, intel, intel-nuc

I am having problems with my audio on Ubuntu 20.04 which is installed on my intel Nuc.
The issue is that I have crackly audio, when watching youtube or using any other software.
I have tried installing pulse audio, and when using the GUI under configuration I have two audio devices, one is Intel CM238 HD and the other is AMD polaris 22 HDMI audio. For the built in audio, the only available profile is Analogue stereo input, and on the Polaris 22, the only available is Digital stereo HDMI 5 output.
If I disable built in audio and leave polaris audio active, I have crackling, and if I disable polaris and leave built in audio on (only available profile is input) I do not have any sound output.

When I initially ran the Ubuntu install I believe I did not install the 3rd party software, as I wasnt planning to use the computer extensively. Even with pulse audio installed and the drivers appearing to work correctly, I still have the static or crackly sound.
I am quite new to Ubuntu so appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar nuc, but the 8i7hnk variety. The built-in audio should be the regular line-out headphone jack, you should get sound output to that jack when you select that as the output.

For the crackling problem going out of HDMI, I found the solution was to edit a line in `/etc/pulse/default.pa` from

```
load-module module-udev-detect
```

to

```
load-module module-udev-detect tsched=0
```

Then, restart your machine or just restart pulseaudio:

```
systemctl --user restart pulseaudio
```

For some details about what this setting does, see [For pulseaudio what does tsched do (and what are the defaults)?](https://askubuntu.com/q/371595/38047)

Comment: it seems to have worked, thank you!